# JSONPath: Get root array object using filter of child value

Tags: java, jsonpath, json-path-expression

Im trying to get JSONPath expression to filter my JSON and get whole sport object using value of child array.

I have following JSON:

```
[{

        "name": "Soccer",
        "regions": [{
                "name": "Australia",
                "leagues": [{
                        "name": "Australia league",
                        "inplay": 5,
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }, {

        "name": "Tennis",
        "regions": [{
                "name": "Germany",
                "leagues": [{
                        "name": "Germany league",
                        "inplay": 0,
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I need to get whole sport object where "inplay == 0" using JsonPath expression.

Result should look like that:

```
 {

    "name": "Tennis",
    "regions": [{
            "name": "Germany",
            "leagues": [{
                    "name": "Germany league",
                    "inplay": 0,
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Regions and Leagues count can be > 1
Therefore `$[?(@.regions[0].leagues[0].inplay == 0)]` is not suitable

Tried `$[?(@.regions[*].leagues[*].inplay == 0)]` but it doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

Since this is not directly supported (as of now) in JayWay JSONPath we leverage `contains` as a [workaround](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath/issues/287#issuecomment-741799718):

```
$[?(@.regions..inplay contains '0')]
```

Note: It may look like contains would work similar to a 'like' operator or `instr` function but this is not the case here. If the `inplay` value contains a 0, e.g. `10` it would not pull the record (according to my tests;)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
$[?(@.regions[0].leagues[0].inplay == 0)]
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. But regions and leagues can be more than 1. 
Tried `$[?(@.regions[*].leagues[*].inplay == 0)]` but it doesnt work

Comment: Yes, deep scan or wild card cannot be used in expression. I think you need to find another way, I run out of idea right now.